# azure HTTP webhook runs forever

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-http-trigger

I am calling an azure function from an Logic app  using azure HTTP Webhook. this  is the parameters used for the call :
[image]

the azure function is lunched and finished working properly and it returns the results with 201 as code status.  this is the output of the azure function:
[image]

Normally the webhook have to finish his work after receiving the 200 code status from the azure function and  go to the next step of the azure logic app, but this is not the case. In fact the logic app is stacked in the azure HTTP Webhook I don't know if this is due to the status code returned by the azure function or due to an other thing.

Any idea about the cause of this problem and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the flow to continue even after receiving a non 200 status code and not failing, explicitly enable run after configuration for Azure function action or any action that you have after http webbook activity.

Here is the configuration :

[image]

For more information please refer this [Blog](https://waelkdouh.medium.com/integrating-azure-functions-with-azure-logic-app-356ea6c10845) .

Comment: thank you @AjayKumarGhose-MT. I am trying to call a durable function using the http webhook, so ASA it receive the request it will return 202 status to the http webhook, than after finishing running, it will return the result associated to the 200 status to the http webhook. then logic app can continue working. So if I implement your solution , just after receiving the 202 status it will continue running which will raise an error in the next step. Also the http webhook is blocked in the "has timed out" which means in progress. the original post : stackoverflow.com/q/69499168/5674606